# Heroku/Django - staticfiles are copied but impossible to display them

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I have a project in heroku but I can't get the static files to work properly.

settings.py:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
```

I've seen a lot of problems were resolved by adding this to urls, so I've done it but it doesn't change anything.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT
}),)
```

then the collectstatic works properly:

```
-----> Preparing static assets
   Running collectstatic...
   673 static files copied to '/app/static'.
```

So they are sent as the command : `heroku run ls -l` say:

```
heroku run ls -l
Running `ls -l` attached to terminal... up, run.9609
total 76
-rw-------  1 u3968 3968   16 2014-10-12 02:05 contributors.txt
drwx------  2 u3968 3968 4096 2014-10-12 02:05 corelib
-rw-------  1 u3968 3968  137 2014-10-12 02:05 dev-requirements.txt
-rwx------  1 u3968 3968  810 2014-10-12 02:05 go.sh
-rw-------  1 u3968 3968    0 2014-10-12 02:05 __init__.py
-rw-------  1 u3968 3968  129 2014-10-12 02:05 __init__.pyc
-rwx------  1 u3968 3968  898 2014-10-12 02:05 manage.py
-rw-------  1 u3968 3968   12 2014-10-12 02:05 Procfile
-rw-------  1 u3968 3968  851 2014-10-12 02:05 requirements.txt
-rw-------  1 u3968 3968   13 2014-10-12 02:05 runtime.txt
-rw-------  1 u3968 3968 7385 2014-10-12 02:05 settings.py
-rw-------  1 u3968 3968 6750 2014-10-12 02:05 settings.pyc
drwx------ 10 u3968 3968 4096 2014-10-12 02:05 static
drwx------  3 u3968 3968 4096 2014-10-12 02:05 templates
drwx------  3 u3968 3968 4096 2014-10-12 02:05 theming
-rw-------  1 u3968 3968 3482 2014-10-12 02:05 urls.py
drwx------  3 u3968 3968 4096 2014-10-12 02:05 useraccount
-rw-------  1 u3968 3968  200 2014-10-12 02:05 wsgi.py
```

but the url /static returns a 404 as the log of heroku:

```
2014-10-12 02:06:05.751101+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/static/css/screen.css"   ... dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=54ms status=404 bytes=1879
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright I've versioned all my staticfiles by sending them to git and so now it works!

I tried to do two opposite things actually... Not sending the static to git and not using a third-app to collect them...

Answer (score 1):

Your URLs are irrelevant, as Django doesn't serve static files when DEBUG is False. You need to configure your server to do it independently: normally you would do that via Apache/nginx, but Heroku doesn't use those. There is however [full documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) on how to get it working, which boils down to installing dj-static and wrapping your WSGI app.

Comment: I am in debug=true as it's just a dev server and I tried to follow this documentation but it didn't work as well... Maybe I missed something following this, I'll try again though.

Comment: ok so now, I have WSGI and dj-static, I am still in DEBUG=True and nothing work again...

Answer (score 0):

Your `settings.py`should be like this:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

...
```

Comment: and if it was a problem of staticfiles_dirs, the collectstatic wouldn't work so it's not from here. Actually letting staticfiles_dirs blank allow my default STATICFILES_FINDERS to kick in to find my staticfiles, it works pretty well like this but my problem is to serving those files once they are on the server (which is the case)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried {% static "css/screen.css" %}

Comment: I had loaded all staticfiles by {% load staticfiles %}